# Pressing "Enter" works in the emulator but not on the phone

Tags: android

it's just a very basic question. Why does it work on the emulator pressing my "real keyboard" enter but not pressing the "enter" on my phone. It just creates a new line.

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
                        || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    todoItems.add(0, myEditText.getText().toString());
                    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    myEditText.setText("");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an old issue that seems not to be solved yet. There's a workaround for these cases. Simply take the `EditText` (or whatever `View` you might be needing this and assign it a `onEditorActionListener`, like this:

```
final EditText editor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editor.setOnEditorActionListener(EnterOnText);
```

Now define the `EnterOnText` implementation like this:

```
TextView.OnEditorActionListener EnterOnText = new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
  public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO) {
      final String msg = view.getText().toString();
      if (!msg.isEmpty()) {
        // Do whatever you need here
        ...
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
};
```

Now, simply change the layout's `imeOptions` attribute to:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

That will, oppositely, probably make your emulator's enter key not work, but will (should) do on all physical devices.

Comment: I don't have much time right now, so maybe I've implemented it wrong.. doesn't work right now for me. But I will try it later again. But seriously, why does something basic like this need a workaround? oO

Comment: Seems that with the new versions the enter key implementation has been changing and it's needed to do. Hope this works when you get some more time.

Comment: Just realized that pressing with the mouse on the HVGA Keyboard but there the enter button which I'm pressing with my finger on the phone it works. Even without your workaround. Is it maybe a CynagonMod thing?

Comment: Not necessarily, but's hard to tell. I had this issue with a S. Galaxy S3, and had to implement the workaround to make it work. It won't be reproducible on all devices, but in order to make it work on all of them (as far as I have tried) I had to keep the workaround up...